# How to configure Stormpath as middleware in Sails.js

Tags: express, sails.js, middleware, stormpath

What is the best way to implement the following code in sails.js v0.10.5?  Should I be handling this with a policy, and if so, how? The init() function required by Stormpath requires Express (app) as an argument.  Currently, I am using the following code in sails.config.http.js as custom middleware.

```
customMiddleware: function(app) {
        var stormpathMiddleware = require('express-stormpath').init(app, {
            apiKeyFile: '',
            application: '',
            secretKey: ''
        });
        app.use(stormpathMiddleware);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the preferred way of enabling custom Express middleware with Sails if it does more than just handling a request (as in your case, where `.init` requires `app`).  For simpler cases where you want to implement custom middleware that just handles requests, you can add the handler to `sails.config.http.middleware` and also add the handler name to the `sails.config.http.middleware.order` array.  See the commented out defaults in `config/http.js` for an example using `myRequestLogger`.

Also note that the `$custom` key in the `sails.config.http.middleware.order` array indicates where the `customMiddleware` code will be executed, so you can change the order if necessary.